# PHP code run on local host but gives error on godaddy server :(

Tags: php

```
$query1="SELECT e.Enrol_id,e.Enrol_date,e.cd_id,e.S_R_id,i.info_Eid,i.Feedback_status,i.e_status from Enrollment e,info_enrol_student i where e.Enrol_id in(select     i.Enrol_id from info_enrol_student where i.ES_Email='$Email') order by     e.enrol_Date DESC";
$conq=mysqli_query($conn,$query1);
if(mysqli_num_rows($conq) > 0){
//any code
}
```

Above code runs on my local host but it gives an error on go daddy server

> warning:mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource boolean
>   given

Comment: Have you change database connection after upload to server?

Comment: it means your `$conn == false` check your DB connection

Comment: all other things like log in 
and other database related things working good
just not working here

Comment: Then you have to check for case sensitive...lower case and uppercase difference works in local but not on live server

Comment: Thanx for that i am checking for it

Comment: thanx its works perfectly :)

Comment: Do not use `mysql_*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible case for this

i). Database connection is not established
But you says Login is working so this is not a problem

ii). Compare all character in your query and check for case sensitive.
   Case sensitive works on local server but not works on live server

Comment: is there any short cute to make live server insensitive for case 

i had write lots of queries without proper case and it is so hard for me to search for all of them :(

Comment: i think No..you can't do anything with server.

Comment: ok thanx for your ans 

it helps me lot

i just find out that i need to change table names only
colum  name can be case insensitive